# When MATCHing to CREATE a node1-[relationship]->node2 set a default node2 (end node) if it doesn't exist

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

If I was doing something like:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (start: {id: "1"})

OPTIONAL MATCH (end: {id: "2"})

CREATE start-[myRelationship:MyRelationshipType { title: "foobar" }]->end
```

If 'end' is null (i.e. it was not found) I want to make end a default node.

I'm loading data from a CSV so this would let me easily identify all the connections that couldn't be formed because of missing end nodes (all nodes that are in the csvs are created before the above, where i'm only trying to setup relationships).

It's a bit of a doozy, any ideas?

@MagnusVortex and I were looking at doing a MERGE but really I feel like i want some kind of conditional (if end IS NULL { end = MATCH {id:"my_default_node"})... something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDITED]

If you want to create a (unique) relationship from an existing `start` node to an existing `end` node (or, if the latter does not exist, to a default node):

```
MATCH (start{ id: "1" }), (default {id:"my_default_node"})
OPTIONAL MATCH (end {id: "2"})
WITH start, CASE WHEN end IS NULL THEN [default] ELSE [end] END AS todo
FOREACH (x IN todo | CREATE UNIQUE (start)-[:MyRelationshipType { title: "foobar"}]->(x));
```

This query does nothing if the `start` or `deafult` nodes are not found. Also, if the `start` node already has an appropriate relationship, this query will make no DB updates.

### Original answer

If you want to create a (unique) relationship from an existing `start` node to an `end` node (that is created if it does not already exist):

```
MATCH (start{ id: "1" })
CREATE UNIQUE (start)-[myRelationship:MyRelationshipType { title: "foobar" }]->(end {id: "2"});
```

This query does nothing if the `start` node is not found. Also, if the `start` node already has a matching relationship (to a matching `end` node), this query will make no DB updates.

#### Less performant solution

As a point of interest, the following query produces the same results (but its profile shows it is much more complex to execute, and probably requires more DB hits):

```
MATCH (start { id: "1" })
MERGE (end { id: "2" })
MERGE (start)-[myRelationship:MyRelationshipType { title: "foobar" }]->(end);
```

Comment: Thanks, i've seen that but I don't really want to be creating those nodes. I just want them all to connect to the same one